# Serving static resources with pax-web in OSGi Felix

Tags: java, osgi, apache-felix, pax-web

I'm stumped with something that should be really simple. I am using pax-web-jetty-bundle 3.0.0 and registering the following:

```
httpService.registerResources("/", "/tmp/static",null);
```

I am however unable to see `/tmp/static/somefile.txt` when accessing `http://localhost:8080/somefile.txt` (I get a 404 not found).

This is just the basic example of course. the `registerResources`  call finishes without incident (I've debugged through) but the resources are simply not served.

I've also tried a more complex example with my own `HttpContext` to no avail: the getResources method is not even called.

I also have other servlets registered with null httpcontextx. Any idea what could be wrong here? Thanks!

Comment: do you have a servlet registered on '/'?

Comment: @PeterKriens no; should I?

Comment: For the record, it turns out this works with pax-web-jetty-bundle 2.1.2, but the exact same code doesn't do anything with pax-web-jetty-bundle *3.0.0*

Comment: No but the servlets and the resources share a single namespace

Comment: @PeterKriens ah ok, so you were worried that I was getting my browser requests sent to the servlet instead of the registered resource. Good idea, but that's not it I"m afraid

Comment: @Miquel, did you give 3.0.1 a try with this? And still might be a regression if it worked with 2.1.2, if so open a issue at pax-web issue tracker at https://ops4j1.jira.com/browse/PAXWEB